# Android Studio App only Debug-Mode

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to program my own App in Android Studio. 
If I run the App in Debug mode, everything works fine. 
But If I start the App in "run-mode", I'll get the dialoge: "Waiting for Debugger..." and nothing happen. Even when I start the app from my Android-menu without a computer connection.

Comment: Have you tried killing the adb.exe in your task manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

Make sure your java files don't have any break points and **Restart the device**

otherwise

`right click on project--> Run as --> Android application`

hope this helps :)

Comment: After a restart, everything works fine... thanks guys!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Close your phone emulator
2. Start "AVD Manager"
3. Click on the down arrow on the right of your listed emulator
4. Click on "Cold Boot Now"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using real phone or emulator? If real phone, try to unplug the phone, delete the app and restart your phone. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I run the application in Debug mode!

I resolved it by doing uncheck and recheck the USB Debugging in developer options.

hope it will help you :)